# Setting bootstrap button to pressed state if checked property is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Clicking the text in `div` does not set bootstrap's state to *pressed*.

To reproduce, run the code snippet below and click in `Set button to pressed state`. The button is still in unpressed state but the alert shows that the *checked* property is set.

How to fix it, so the buttons appear in the *checked* state if clicked in the text inside the `div` ?

The Bootstrap documentation contains:

> If the checked state of a checkbox button is updated without firing a click event on the button (e.g. via  or via setting the checked property of the input), you will need to toggle the .active class on the input's label yourself.

Shoud this be implemented and if yes, how ?

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.designer-field').on("click", function () {
                $('#designer-javascript-bold').prop('checked', true);
                // alert($('#designer-javascript-bold').prop('checked'));
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="designer-javascript-bold"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span>
        </label>

    </div>
    <div class="designer-field">Set button to pressed state</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to trigger the class change on the parent label. The plugin you are using does not do that automatically on manual trigger it seems.

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.designer-field').on("click", function () {
                $('#designer-javascript-bold').prop('checked', true);
                $('#designer-javascript-bold').parent().toggleClass('active');
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="designer-javascript-bold"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bold"></span>
        </label>

    </div>
    <div class="designer-field">Set button to pressed state</div>
</body>
```